# OpenCV get coordinates of red-only rectangle area

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have the following output from red-only filtration done by the following algorithm:

```
cv::Mat findColor(const cv::Mat & inputBGRimage, int rng=20)
{
    // Make sure that your input image uses the channel order B, G, R (check not implemented).
    cv::Mat mt1, mt2;
    cv::Mat input = inputBGRimage.clone();
    cv::Mat imageHSV; //(input.rows, input.cols, CV_8UC3);
    cv::Mat imgThreshold, imgThreshold0, imgThreshold1; //(input.rows, input.cols, CV_8UC1);

    assert( ! input.empty() );

    // blur image
    cv::blur( input, input, Size(11, 11) );

    // convert input-image to HSV-image
    cv::cvtColor( input, imageHSV, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV );

    // In the HSV-color space the color 'red' is located around the H-value 0 and also around the
    // H-value 180. That is why you need to threshold your image twice and the combine the results.
    cv::inRange( imageHSV, cv::Scalar( H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN ), cv::Scalar( H_MAX, S_MAX, V_MAX ), imgThreshold0 );

    if ( rng > 0 )
    {
        // cv::inRange(imageHSV, cv::Scalar(180-rng, 53, 185, 0), cv::Scalar(180, 255, 255, 0), imgThreshold1);
        // cv::bitwise_or( imgThreshold0, imgThreshold1, imgThreshold );
    }
    else
    {
        imgThreshold = imgThreshold0;
    }

    // cv::dilate( imgThreshold0, mt1, Mat() );

    // cv::erode( mt1, mt2, Mat() );

    return imgThreshold0;

}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

And I want to detect the four coordinates of the rectangle. As you can see, the output is not perfect, I used `cv::findContours` in conjunction with `cv::approxPolyDP` before, but it's not working good anymore.

Is there any filter that I can apply for input image (except blur, dilate, erode) to make image better for processing?

Any suggestions?

**Updated:**

When I am using `findContours` like this:

```
findContours( src, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

double largest_area = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {  // get the largest contour
    area = fabs( contourArea( contours[i] ) );
    if( area >= largest_area ) {
        largest_area = area;
        largestContours.clear();
        largestContours.push_back( contours[i] );
    }
}

if( largest_area > 5000 ) {
    cv::approxPolyDP( cv::Mat(largestContours[0]), approx, 100, true );
    cout << approx.size() << endl; /* ALWAYS RETURN 2 ?!? */
}
```

The `approxPolyDP` is not working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your result is quite good, maybe if you select the contour with greatest area using [Image Moments](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html) and then finding the minimal rotated rectangle of the bigger contour.

```
vector<cv::RotatedRect> cv::minRect( contours.size() );

for( size_t = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
    minRect[i] = minAreaRect( cv::Mat(contours[i]) );
}
```

[Rotated Rect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=rotatedrect#RotatedRect) class already has a vector of Point2f to store the points.

```
RotatedRect rRect = RotatedRect(Point2f(100,100), Size2f(100,50), 30);
Point2f vertices[4];
rRect.points(vertices);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    std::cout << vertices[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to detect the coordinates of 4 points using RotatedRect?

Comment: @unixarmy - You can use `findContours` and employ the `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` flag.  Given an upright rectangular shape, this should result in 4 points being detected in the shape, corresponding to the corner points.  See here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours

Comment: rayryeng suggestion might actually solve your problem.

Comment: @rayryeng, can you check the updated answer? I think it's not working as excepted.

Comment: The `approx.size()` always return 2, even if I have a "good" rectangle.

Comment: Don't use `approxPolyDP`. You just use the contour points directly. That's why it isn't working